# Home Work Help: Calculating Entropy for Melting Ice - Clarification on answer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, error-analysis

The question states:
 `What is the change in entropy for the process to completely melt 8.0 kg of ice at 0°C?`

The formulas for Entropy we've been introduced to are:
S = Q/T - for constant temperature
ΔS = ∫dQ/T

For heat:
Q=mcΔT
Q=Lm
ΔQ=CΔT
ΔQ=mcΔT

My approach was find the heat to melt the ice: 
Q=Lm
m = 8.0kg
L<sub>f ice</sub>=337kJ/kg
Q=8.0kg*337kJ/kg = 2696kJ

Now sub this in for constant temperature using Kelvin
S = Q/T

S = 2696kJ / 273.15K
S = 9.78 kJ/K

The answer is given as 10 kJ/K. Usually in this subject an answer would be 2 significant figures as standard so I'm a little unsure if I've actually got the correct answer or if I'm close by coincidence and have completely missed the question.

Comment: Your methodology is correct.  I haven't checked your arithmetic.  If it is correct, then, to two significant figures, $\Delta S=9.8$kJ/K

Comment: Some books and computer homework systems enforce significant figures inconsistently, sporadically, and incorrectly.  Unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really concerns error analysis.  The subject (thermodynamics) is irrelevant.

The "usual" custom of 2 significant figures is always subject to the data actually provided.

The data here is 8.0kg and 0°C = 273K.  The former is 2 sig figs; the latter is 3 sig figs.  As a rough guide, if the calculation involves only multiplications and divisions, the answer should be quoted to no more than 2 sig figs, the smallest in the data.  If several consecutive calculations are made, a full error analysis might reduce this further to 1 sig fig.

Therefore 9.8kJ/K (2sf) or 10 kJ/K (1sf) are correct, but not not 9.78kJ/K (3sf).

You are very unlikely to be so close by coincidence.